# Android, How to handle change in network (from GPRS to Wi-fi and vice-versa) while polling for data

Tags: android, wifi, android-networking, gprs

I use [DefaultHttpClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpClient.html) and [HttpGet](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpGet.html) to poll data from server. Now, say a user was in Wi-fi network and moves out of the room. So the phone automatically starts using the 3G network. Are there any call-backs for such change, and how should I handle such changes. Should I start polling again or does the OS take care to make the changes appropriately

Answer (score 17):

You can set up a Receiver in your manifest:

```
<receiver
  android:name=".NetworkChangeReceiver"
  android:label="NetworkChangeReceiver">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
    <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

And implement the `Receiver` with something like this:

```
public class NetworkChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

  @Override
  public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
    final ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) 
    context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    final android.net.NetworkInfo wifi = 
    connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

    final android.net.NetworkInfo mobile = 
    connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);

    if (wifi.isAvailable()) {
      //Do something
    if (mobile.isAvailable()) {
      //Do something else
    }
  }
}
```

If you are keeping a persistent connection it will go down and you have to re-establish it.

If you are scheduling a service and you are not keeping the connection persistent, you will not have problems.

Answer (score -3):

I think nothing you need to do ,but you should guarantee that your server's IP address is not arranged randomly,that is to say you should have a fixed IP address.That's my answer;

Comment: I think it's more likely that the client (on a mobile device) might change its' IP address. This does not answer OP's question from March of 2011.