# How to monitor internet connection loss in android service

Tags: android

I want to write an android service at is activated when the internet connection goes down, and displays another activity to user when that happens. I don't know how to start to write this service. Can any one give me an idea or better tutorial how to catch the connection down within Android service.

Thanks

Comment: if u have connection problem to refer this link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5165099/android-how-to-handle-change-in-network-from-gprs-to-wi-fi-and-vice-versa-whi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When Internet connectivity changes, the system sends out a broadcast with an [`android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#CONNECTIVITY_ACTION) intent. You should be able to create a [broadcast receiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) that will be called whenever the device is connected or loses its connection.

Comment: Can i use AsyncTask in Broadcast Receiver

Answer (score 1):

You've to write a receiver for the connection changes.

You can look right here : [Android, How to handle change in network (from GPRS to Wi-fi and vice-versa) while polling for data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5165099/android-how-to-handle-change-in-network-from-gprs-to-wi-fi-and-vice-versa-whi)