# Android HTTP progressive streaming onBufferingUpdate stops being called after a few seconds

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, audio-streaming, http-streaming, progressive-download

I have developed an Android music player app that can stream MP3s via HTTP progressive download (via WiFi, using Apache). This is how I set up the `MediaPlayer` to stream the MP3:

```
mediaplayer.setDataSource(192.168.../song.mp3)
```

Everything works fine until the connection to the server is lost. From the log outputs of my registered `onBufferingUpdateListener`, it seems that when the connection to the server is lost (say, I turn off WiFi on my phone), `MediaPlayer` attempts to fill up the remaining song in its buffer. However this retrying stops after a few seconds.

In other words, if a connection to the server is not resumed within a few seconds of it being lost, `MediaPlayer` will *not* resume buffering. (i.e. `onBufferingUpdate()` stops getting called after a few seconds of retrying). Also, I receive no errors/info messages in my `onInfoListener` or `onErrorListener`.

**The question is**: How do I force `MediaPlayer` to resume buffering the rest of the song(preferably without interrupting playback) when a connection to the server is available again regardless of the time interval between successive connections?

What alternatives do I have to stream MP3s via HTTP progressive download?

Comment: For that i suggest that check connection response code in a particular time after the lost the connection if you get the connection back at that time request to server with last buffered bytes..

Comment: Reference :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11713696/android-mediaplayer-streaming-stops-on-network-change?rq=1