# Intent for change in preferred network

Tags: android, android-intent

Is there any intent generated when the preferred network is changed on android?

Though WIFI has the higher priority when both Mobile data and WIFI are turned on.but it can be changed using this statement

```
connectivityManager.setNetworkPreference(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
```

However,if I  query preferred network immediately after the above statement using

```
connectivityManager.getNetworkPreference()
```

I still get `ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI` as return value.

So it seems that `setNetworkPreference` doesn't change preferred network immediately.

My question,

**Is there any intent generated for change in network preference?**

Answer (score 0):

Create a broadcast receiver listening for:

```
<action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"/>
```

See 
[Android, How to handle change in network (from GPRS to Wi-fi and vice-versa) while polling for data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5165099/android-how-to-handle-change-in-network-from-gprs-to-wi-fi-and-vice-versa-whi) for an example.

Comment: I checked that but change of network preference is not detected by this intent-filter.